# Connotation for "unsolicited"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

The main question is if using "unsolicited" implies a negative connotation? My original intention is simply to express "spontaneous" in the situation. Why not "spontaneous"? Perhaps it gives a feeling of lacking temperature.

So i) Is "unsolicited" somewhat negative? ii) Is "spontaneous" a more reasonable choice?.

Comment: "Spontaneous" has more of a connotation of being not planned or unpremeditated - "spontaneous laughter" is a surprise to both the person being laughed at *and* to the person doing the laughing.  If something is "unsolicited," however, it's only surprising to the recipient.

Comment: "Unprompted" is an alternative which never, as far as I know, has a negative connotation.

Comment: @ColinFine, Hi, thanks a lot. Yes, that sounds quite neutral; thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Unsolicited does not necessarily have a negative implication. It means "not asked for, and sometimes not wanted". The implication, positive, neutral, or negative, is supplied by the context. Unsolicited praise is a generally a good thing. Unsolicited phone calls, letters and visits from sales people might be a nuisance.

Answer (score 0):

Unsolicited, in some settings, means "not asked for, because not wanted". Example: "unsolicited advice" can sound like it was foisted on someone who was clearly not needing or going to value it.